# Java/LibGDX Self made Input Field

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to create an Inputfield from Scratch in Java and LibGDX, my Question is:
How can I display only certain Parts of a String in a specific width?

For example:
My Input field GUI is 200 pixels wide. But I can write like 500 Letters maximum in my Input field. When I display this 500 letters all at once. It would be bigger than the GUI. So I want when I wrote down the first 100 letters and then write the next one that the first one disappears and the displayed text starts from the 2 Letter and then goes to the 101. And so on. Much like the Minecraft Chat Input field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to measure on-screen width the string contained by the control and compare that to the width of the control. If it is too wide, skip the first character and try again.

[image: custom Actor]

The `GlyphLayout` class in **libGDX** can help you here.

A naive implementation may look like this:

```
package com.bornander.playground3d;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.GlyphLayout;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;

public class CustomInput extends Actor {

    private static final String TEMPLATE = "The quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog. ";

    private int index = 0;
    private float elapsed;
    private BitmapFont font;
    private StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    public CustomInput(Skin skin) {
        font = skin.getFont("default-font");
        setWidth(100);
        setHeight(font.getLineHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        // Just pretend a character is typed every .2 second
        elapsed += delta;
        if (elapsed > 0.2f) {
            elapsed = 0;
            text.append(TEMPLATE.charAt((index++) % TEMPLATE.length()));
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        font.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        // Try to fit the full text, if after measuring it it turns out to be too long, 
        // skip the first character and try again
        String textToDisplay = text.toString();
        for(int i = 0; i < text.toString().length(); ++i) {
            textToDisplay = text.toString().substring(i);

            GlyphLayout glyphLayout = new GlyphLayout(font, textToDisplay);
            if (glyphLayout.width < getWidth()) {
                break;
            }
        }

        font.draw(batch, textToDisplay, getX(), getY() + font.getLineHeight());
    }
}
```

In the above example I have ignored the task of attaching a key listener and the control simply adds a character every .2 seconds, also no consideration has been given to performance.

Comment: Glad you liked it @GentleXD, consider marking the answer as accepted if it solved your issue.